# A call to PInvoke OpenSqlFilestream function has unbalanced the stack

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

I am using Filestream feature of SQL Server.
When I try to access the following method :

```
[DllImport("sqlncli10.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern SafeFileHandle OpenSqlFilestream(string path, uint access, uint options, byte[] txnToken, uint txnTokenLength, Sql64 allocationSize);

SafeFileHandle handle = OpenSqlFilestream(filePath, (uint)access, 0, txnToken, (uint)txnToken.Length, new Sql64(0));
```

is the calling method.

A call to PInvoke OpenSqlFilestream function  has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

What could be the reason?

I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DllImport( "sqlncli11.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]  //sqlncli10.dll

private static extern SafeFileHandle OpenSqlFilestream(String filestreamPath, UInt32 desiredAccess, UInt32 openOptions, Byte[] filestreamTransactionContext, UInt32 filestreamTransactionContextLength, Int64 allocationSize );
```